# Categorizizng variable with multiple values in one cell and tallying in R

Tags: r

Reposting this question to clarify my objective- I am trying to create a new categorical variable "Income" (3 levels) that categorizes a subset of predetermined countries (x, y, z) into the different levels. My issue is that the countries variable has multiple countries in each cell, so I don't know how to sort this.

What I'm hoping to get:

```
ID           country             **income**
1            Chad, USA, USA, USA   LMIC, HMIC, HMIC, HMIC
2            USA                   HMIC
3            Ethiopia, USA, Chad   LMIC, HMIC, LMIC
1            Albania, Canada       UMIC, HMIC
```

so tally would result in LMIC = 2 (as ID 1 and 3 contain LMIC, and they would count one per entry rather than lmic = 3 total), HMIC = 4 (as ID 1-4 contain HMIC), and UMIC = 1 (ID 4).

This is the code I have based one someone's recommendation. However, it turns n=134,086 observations (publications) into n=388,844, so when I tally the levels of Income, I get values like HMIC = 305k. My goal is to tally among the original publication count such that I can calc what proportion of n=134k were LMIC, LMIC, etc. This would mean that the Income cells (by ID) that have multiple values like "HMIC, HMIC, HMIC, LMIC" would count as one HMIC and one LMIC when I tally. Is there a way to do this?

```
data.set %>% separate_rows(country, sep = ",")
data.set %>% mutate(Income = case_when(country %in% c("USA", "Canada", "Japan") ~ "HMIC", country %in% c("Albania", "Argentina") ~ "UMIC", country %in% c("Chad", "Ethiopia") ~ "LMIC", TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

Comment: What about `df %>% mutate(country = str_split(country, ",\\s?")) %>% unnest_longer(country)`, then the same procedure as last time? If you can group_by ID and nest again afterwards if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `separate_rows` on both `income` and `country` at once, get rid of the duplicate `income` categories using e.g. `distinct` and use `count`:

Note: I adjusted your example data which contained a duplicated ID=1 in the fourth row which I replaced by ID=4.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.set <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), country = c(
  "Chad, USA, USA, USA",
  "USA", "Ethiopia, USA, Chad", "Albania, Canada"
), income = c(
  "LMIC, HMIC, HMIC, HMIC",
  "HMIC", "LMIC, HMIC, LMIC", "UMIC, HMIC"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -4L
))

data.set %>%
  separate_rows(country, income, sep = ", ") %>%
  distinct(ID, income) %>%
  count(income)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   income     n
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 HMIC       4
#> 2 LMIC       2
#> 3 UMIC       1
```

**EDIT** If I understand you right you want to do two things. First you want to create an `income` variable which assigns countries to income groups. Second you want to summarise your data. To solve the first task you could use `recode` or `case_when` as suggested in the answer on your former question or in the comments. As an alternative I would suggest to first create a lookup table which via a `left_join` could be used to add your income variable after applying `separate_rows`. After this step you could go on with the code I provided to get the counts per income group:

```r
# Get rid of income column
data.set <- data.set %>%
  select(-income)

# Create a recode or lookup table which assigns countries to income groups
recode_table <- structure(list(country = c(
  "Chad", "USA", "Ethiopia", "Albania",
  "Canada"
), income = c("LMIC", "HMIC", "LMIC", "UMIC", "HMIC")), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data.set %>%
  separate_rows(country, sep = ", ") %>%
  left_join(recode_table, by = "country") |> 
  distinct(ID, income) %>%
  count(income)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   income     n
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 HMIC       4
#> 2 LMIC       2
#> 3 UMIC       1
```

Comment: Hello! The issue I'm running into with this is that the original data has many cells with multiple countries, so when I recode for example USA = HMIC, it will only change the cells with just USA to HMIC in the new Income variable, and the other cells like "USA, Canada, Japan" remain unchanged. Additionally, there are too many combinations for me to hand-rename all of them (each entry is a publication, and the country variable = all the countries of the corresponding authors (could be up to 10)

Comment: Is there a way for me to use if then or another function such that if "country" has a "USA" then *new variable* Income has HMIC (if there are multiple USA in the same cell, Income will still only have one HMIC); as such, a "country" cell with "USA, USA, Canada, Ethiopia, Chad" will result in an Income cell of "HMIC, LMIC"

Comment: Sorry. I just had another look at your question(s) and now I see that I have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve. I just made an edit. Maybe this time I got your right.